# How to overwrite an item with a different schema but same key in DynamoDB using nodejs on lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to overwrite an item in DynamoDB (that uses a primary key called `username`) by using `put` as shown below:

```
        console.log('writing commands',existingCommands,message.username);
        var t2 = performance();
        var writeParams = {
            Item: {
                username: message.username,
                commands: existingCommands // Sorry for the confusing name, due to deepExtend existingCommands are the new commands
            },

            TableName: TableName
        };

        docClient.put(writeParams, function(err, data){
            if(err){
                console.error('error',err);
            } else {
                console.log('write result',data);
                var t3 = performance();
                console.info('delete & write performance',(t3-t2).toFixed(3));
            }
            // End function
            context.done();
        });
```

That works for:

- Inserting a new item where the `username` doesn't exist.
- Updating an item that matches the schema of the Item i'm trying to insert, for example, I'm trying to insert that item:

  ```
  {
     "username":"ausin441062133",
      "commands": {
        "command1":"command",
        "command2":"command"
      }
  }
  ```

and if there's an item that matches the schema and the username it'll get overwritten, i.e.

```
    {
       "username":"ausin441062133",
        "commands": {
          "command1":"I will be overwritten",
          "command2":"I will be overwritten"
        }
    }
```

But when there's an item with the exact username but different schema, it doesn't work, i.e.

```
    {
       "username":"ausin441062133",
        "commands": {
          "command1":"I will NOT be overwritten"
        }
    }
```

What command do I need to use to overwrite an existing item if it matches the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually as Dmitry suggested `update` works but it needs some different params as opposed to `put` here's my code:

```
        // Step 3 write command back
        console.log('writing commands',existingCommands,message.username);
        var t2 = performance();
        var updateParams = {
            Key: {
                username: message.username
            },
            UpdateExpression: "set commands = :c",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":c":existingCommands
            },
            ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
            TableName: TableName
        };

        docClient.update(updateParams, function(err, data){
            if(err){
                console.error('error',err);
            } else {
                console.log('write result',data);
                var t3 = performance();
                console.info('delete & write performance',(t3-t2).toFixed(3));
            }
            // End function
            context.done();
        });
```